# Need to scrape an url from a web page

Tags: java, android, regex, parsing, pattern-matching

I need to scrape a url from a website which is located within some javascript code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
        // somewhere..
        $.get("http://someurl.com?q=34343&b=343434&c=343434")...
    });
</script>
```

I know that the url starts with `http://someurl.com?q=` and it needs to have at least a second query parameter (`&b=`) inside, but the rest of the content is unknown.

I initially tried with *jsoup*, however it's not really suitable for that task. Manually fetching the page and then applying a regex pattern on it is also not a preferable option since the page is huge. What could I do to get the url quick and safe?

Comment: IMHO, there is nothing wrong with using a regex on a huge page. It will only be a bit slower.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex

```
/\$\.get\("(http:\/\/someurl\.com\?q=[\w.\-%#\/]*&b=[\w.\-%&=\/]*)"\)/g
```

This regex will search directly for this string:

```
$.get("http://someurl.com?q=
```

It will then allow any number of URL valid characters to occur as the value of q.

It will then look to match

```
&b=
```

and then again any number of valid characters followed by  the opposing quotation marks. I tested it with

```
MATCH - $.get("http://someurl.com?q=34343&b=343434&c=343434")
MATCH - $.get("http://someurl.com?q=34343&b=13a43&k=343434&c2=something")
FAIL  - $.get("http://someurl.com?q=34343&c=343434&b=343434")
FAIL  - $.get("http://someurl.com?a=34343&b=343434=343434")
```

If you only want to return the first result you can remove the global identifier from the end

```
/\$\.get\("(http:\/\/someurl\.com\?q=[\w.\-%#\/]*&b=[\w.\-%&=\/]*)"\)/
```